# How to store Golang time.time in Postgresql timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, go

May I know how to store the `time.time` object in Postgresql?

For example, the SQL query:

`INSERT INTO "UserAccount" ("email", "login_time") VALUES ('human@example.com', 2017-12-12 00:58:26.9589451 +0800 +08 m=+1406.914186601)`

I tried to use `loginTime := time.Now()`, and it gives a time format that Postgresql don't really understand, e.g. *2017-12-12 00:58:26.9589451 +0800 +08 m=+1406.914186601*

But if I try to use `loginTime := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)`, and the compiler complain that `loginTime` is a `string`, and I need it to be `time.time` type.

May I know how to handle this?

*Sorry for asking newbie question, new to both Golang and Postgres. :)*

Comment: In addition to what the answers recommend, you can also convert a valid timestamp string into a `timestamp` or `timestamptz` in the postgres query like so `'2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00'::timestamp` / `'2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00'::timestamptz`, works also with placeholders `$2::timestamp`... Just make sure the timestamp string has a format that is accepted by postgres, the one in your example **is not**.

Comment: this might help https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 21):

Instead of manually building the query string you should use [`sql#DB.Exec(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec) with placeholder parameters so that the database driver properly escapes the values for you. Doing it this way is a best-practice, especially to avoid security errors such as [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
email, loginTime := "human@example.com", time.Now()
result, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO UserAccount VALUES ($1, $2)", email, loginTime)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Note that Postgres does not support the `?` placeholder.  You must use `$1` and `$2`, or use something like [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx)'s `Rebind()` function.

Answer (score 9):

The pq driver (which I assume you are using) automatically converts time.Time instances correctly for you.

so, you can do:

```
db.Exec(`INSERT INTO "UserAccount" ("email", "login_time") VALUES ($1, $2)`,"human@example.com",time.Now())
```