# How to use time.Time in a postgres query?

Tags: postgresql, go, pq

I am using pq library in golang for postgres queries. I want to pass timestamp in the query string.

Ex. `query = 'SELECT \* FROM table WHERE ts \<= NOW() - interval '5 seconds''`

Instead of `NOW()` ...can I pass a timestamp?

Ex.

```
t=time.Now()

query = 'SELECT \* FROM table WHERE ts \<= t- interval '5 seconds''
```

I tried formatting the timestamp and using arguments to pass the timestamp but getting errors.

Comment: You can pass a `time.Time` directly as value to a prepared statement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758359/how-to-store-golang-time-time-in-postgresql-timestamp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store Golang time.time in Postgresql timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758359/how-to-store-golang-time-time-in-postgresql-timestamp)